# MariaDB: multiple table update does not update a single row multiple times? Why?

Tags: sql-update, mariadb

Today I was just bitten in the rear end by something I didn't expect. Here's a little script to reproduce the issue:

```
create temporary table aaa_state(id int, amount int);
create temporary table aaa_changes(id int, delta int);

insert into aaa_state(id, amount) values (1, 0);
insert into aaa_changes(id, delta) values (1, 5), (1, 7);

update aaa_changes c join aaa_state s on (c.id=s.id) set s.amount=s.amount+c.delta;

select * from aaa_state;
```

The final result in the `aaa_state` table is:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

Whereas I would expect it to be:

| ID | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |

What gives? I [checked the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/update/) but cannot find anything that would hint at this behavior. Is this a bug that I should report, or is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing is consistent with *two* updates happening on the `aaa_state` table.  One update is assigning the amount to 7, and then this amount is being clobbered by the second update, which sets to 5.  This could be explained by MySQL using a snapshot of the `aaa_state` table to fetch the `amount` for each step of the update.  If true, the actual steps would look something like this:

```
1. join the two tables
2. update the amount using the "first" row from the changes table.
   now the cached result for the amount is 7, but this value will not actually
   be written out to the underlying table until AFTER the entire update
3. update the amount using the "second" row from the changes table.
   now the cached amount is 5
5. the update is over, write 5 out for the actual amount
```

Your syntax is not really correct for what you want to do.  You should be using something like the following:

```sql
UPDATE aaa_state as
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, SUM(delta) AS delta_sum
    FROM aaa_changes
    GROUP BY id
) ac
    ON ac.id = as.id
SET
    as.amount = as.amount + ac.delta_sum;
```

Here we are doing a proper aggregation of the delta values for each `id` in a separate bona-fide subquery.  This means that the delta sums will be properly computed *and* materialized in the subquery before MySQL does the join, to update the first table.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'll rewrite it to, it's the obvious workaround, but I'm surprised that it doesn't work without it. I understand that the modified data isn't visible outside the transaction, but why does it take a snapshot here and use it like that? Is that correct?

Comment: The problem is being caused by that logically because the `aaa_state` record matches to _two_ records in the `aaa_changes` table, MySQL has to figure out what to do (if you think about this, it won't be clear in your head either about how to interpret this).  MySQL has some rules around updates.  For example, you probably know that you can't refer to the same table in an update under certain conditions.  Add this to the list.

Comment: Ahh... if you look at it that way (as updating one JOINed super-table, rather than two individual tables), then what you're saying is starting to make sense.

Comment: @Vilx- I suspect that maybe you are coming from an application development point of view, and so thought to do it this way.

Comment: I've been comfortable in all kinds of RDBMs and SQL dialects for more than a decade, but a multi-table update is not something I've done often so somehow I got the wrong image in my head. :)

Comment: Some databases (e.g. Oracle) don't even support update join syntax, perhaps related to this very reason.  Others do, but have caveats.